# How to get currency name from JSON file in AJAX call and PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I pass country name in AJAX call in order to obtain currency name from JSON file by using PHP script.

I can pass country names to server in AJAX call, but I struggle to get currency country back from the server.

I get the error message to say that my currency name is null.

Here is my PHP script and AJAX call

```
<?php




$jsonResponse = file_get_contents('country-by-currency-name.json');

$jsonResponse = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);




$output = null;
foreach ($jsonResponse as $countryData) {
    $country = $countryData['country'];
    if ($country == $_REQUEST['country']) {
        $currencyName = $countryData['currency_name'];

        $output = $currencyName;



        break;

    }
    ;
}





header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($output);
```

```
let countryN = $('#selCountry').text(); // when i console.log(countryN), I get the country names in the console. 

$.ajax({

                url: './currencyAPI.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    country: countryN



                },
                success: function (result2) {


                    $('#currency').html(result2['0']['currency_name']);



                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(" No current location data available.")
                }
            })
```

here is the JSON file

```
[
    {
        "country": "Afghanistan",
        "currency_name": "Afghanistan Afghani"
    },
    {
        "country": "Albania",
        "currency_name": "Albanian Lek"
    },
    {
        "country": "Algeria",
        "currency_name": "Algerian Dinar"
    },
    {
        "country": "American Samoa",
        "currency_name": "US Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Andorra",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Angola",
        "currency_name": "Angolan Kwanza"
    },
    {
        "country": "Anguilla",
        "currency_name": "East Caribbean Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Antarctica",
        "currency_name": "East Caribbean Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Antigua and Barbuda",
        "currency_name": "East Caribbean Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Argentina",
        "currency_name": "Argentine Peso"
    },
    {
        "country": "Armenia",
        "currency_name": "Armenian Dram"
    },
    {
        "country": "Aruba",
        "currency_name": "Aruban Guilder"
    },
    {
        "country": "Australia",
        "currency_name": "Australian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Austria",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Azerbaijan",
        "currency_name": "Azerbaijan New Manat"
    },
    {
        "country": "Bahamas",
        "currency_name": "Bahamian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Bahrain",
        "currency_name": "Bahraini Dinar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Bangladesh",
        "currency_name": "Bangladeshi Taka"
    },
    {
        "country": "Barbados",
        "currency_name": "Barbados Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Belarus",
        "currency_name": "Belarussian Ruble"
    },
    {
        "country": "Belgium",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Belize",
        "currency_name": "Belize Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Benin",
        "currency_name": "CFA Franc BCEAO"
    },
    {
        "country": "Bermuda",
        "currency_name": "Bermudian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Bhutan",
        "currency_name": "Bhutan Ngultrum"
    },
    {
        "country": "Bolivia",
        "currency_name": "Boliviano"
    },
    {
        "country": "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
        "currency_name": "Convertible Mark"
    },
    {
        "country": "Botswana",
        "currency_name": "Botswana Pula"
    },
    {
        "country": "Bouvet Island",
        "currency_name": "Norwegian Krone"
    },
    {
        "country": "Brazil",
        "currency_name": "Brazilian Real"
    },
    {
        "country": "British Indian Ocean Territory",
        "currency_name": "US Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Brunei",
        "currency_name": "Brunei Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Bulgaria",
        "currency_name": "Bulgarian Lev"
    },
    {
        "country": "Burkina Faso",
        "currency_name": "CFA Franc BCEAO"
    },
    {
        "country": "Burundi",
        "currency_name": "Burundi Franc"
    },
    {
        "country": "Cambodia",
        "currency_name": "Kampuchean Riel"
    },
    {
        "country": "Cameroon",
        "currency_name": "CFA Franc BEAC"
    },
    {
        "country": "Canada",
        "currency_name": "Canadian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Cape Verde",
        "currency_name": "Cape Verde Escudo"
    },
    {
        "country": "Cayman Islands",
        "currency_name": "Cayman Islands Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Central African Republic",
        "currency_name": "CFA Franc BEAC"
    },
    {
        "country": "Chad",
        "currency_name": "Central African"
    },
    {
        "country": "Chile",
        "currency_name": "Chilean Peso"
    },
    {
        "country": "China",
        "currency_name": "Yuan Renminbi"
    },
    {
        "country": "Christmas Island",
        "currency_name": "Australian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Cocos (Keeling) Islands",
        "currency_name": " Australian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Colombia",
        "currency_name": "Colombian Peso"
    },
    {
        "country": "Comoros",
        "currency_name": "Comoros Franc"
    },
    {
        "country": "Congo",
        "currency_name": "CFA Franc BEAC"
    },
    {
        "country": "Cook Islands",
        "currency_name": "New Zealand Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Costa Rica",
        "currency_name": "Costa Rican Colon"
    },
    {
        "country": "Croatia",
        "currency_name": "Croatian Kuna"
    },
    {
        "country": "Cuba",
        "currency_name": "Cuban Peso"
    },
    {
        "country": "Cyprus",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Czech Republic",
        "currency_name": "Czech Koruna"
    },
    {
        "country": "Denmark",
        "currency_name": "Danish Krone"
    },
    {
        "country": "Djibouti",
        "currency_name": "Djibouti Franc"
    },
    {
        "country": "Dominica",
        "currency_name": "East Caribbean Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Dominican Republic",
        "currency_name": "Dominican Peso"
    },
    {
        "country": "East Timor",
        "currency_name": "US Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Ecuador",
        "currency_name": "Ecuador Sucre"
    },
    {
        "country": "Egypt",
        "currency_name": "Egyptian Pound"
    },
    {
        "country": "El Salvador",
        "currency_name": "El Salvador Colon"
    },
    {
        "country": "England",
        "currency_name": "Pound Sterlin"
    },
    {
        "country": "Equatorial Guinea",
        "currency_name": "CFA Franc BEAC"
    },
    {
        "country": "Eritrea",
        "currency_name": "Eritrean Nakfa"
    },
    {
        "country": "Estonia",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Ethiopia",
        "currency_name": "Ethiopian Birr"
    },
    {
        "country": "Falkland Islands",
        "currency_name": "Falkland Islands Pound"
    },
    {
        "country": "Faroe Islands",
        "currency_name": " Danish Krone"
    },
    {
        "country": "Fiji Islands",
        "currency_name": "Fijian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Finland",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "France",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "French Guiana",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "French Polynesia",
        "currency_name": "CFP Franc"
    },
    {
        "country": "French Southern territories",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Gabon",
        "currency_name": "CFA Franc BEAC"
    },
    {
        "country": "Gambia",
        "currency_name": "Gambian Dalasi"
    },
    {
        "country": "Georgia",
        "currency_name": "Georgian Lari"
    },
    {
        "country": "Germany",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Ghana",
        "currency_name": "Ghanaian Cedi"
    },
    {
        "country": "Gibraltar",
        "currency_name": "Gibraltar Pound"
    },
    {
        "country": "Greece",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Greenland",
        "currency_name": "Danish Krone"
    },
    {
        "country": "Grenada",
        "currency_name": "East Carribean Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Guadeloupe",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Guam",
        "currency_name": "US Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Guatemala",
        "currency_name": "Guatemalan Quetzal"
    },
    {
        "country": "Guinea",
        "currency_name": "Guinea Franc"
    },
    {
        "country": "Guinea-Bissau",
        "currency_name": "West African CFA franc"
    },
    {
        "country": "Guyana",
        "currency_name": "Guyana Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Haiti",
        "currency_name": "Haitian Gourde"
    },
    {
        "country": "Heard Island and McDonald Islands",
        "currency_name": "Australian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Holy See (Vatican City State)",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Honduras",
        "currency_name": "Honduran Lempira"
    },
    {
        "country": "Hong Kong",
        "currency_name": "Hong Kong Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Hungary",
        "currency_name": "Hungarian Forint"
    },
    {
        "country": "Iceland",
        "currency_name": "Iceland Krona"
    },
    {
        "country": "India",
        "currency_name": "Indian Rupee"
    },
    {
        "country": "Indonesia",
        "currency_name": "Indonesian Rupiah"
    },
    {
        "country": "Iran",
        "currency_name": "Iranian Rial"
    },
    {
        "country": "Iraq",
        "currency_name": "Iraqi Dinar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Ireland",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Israel",
        "currency_name": "Israeli New Shekel"
    },
    {
        "country": "Italy",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Ivory Coast",
        "currency_name": "CFA Franc BCEAO"
    },
    {
        "country": "Jamaica",
        "currency_name": "Jamaican Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Japan",
        "currency_name": "Japanese Yen"
    },
    {
        "country": "Jordan",
        "currency_name": "Jordanian Dinar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Kazakhstan",
        "currency_name": "Tenge"
    },
    {
        "country": "Kenya",
        "currency_name": "Kenyan Shilling"
    },
    {
        "country": "Kiribati",
        "currency_name": "Australian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Kuwait",
        "currency_name": "Kuwaiti Dinar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Kyrgyzstan",
        "currency_name": "Som"
    },
    {
        "country": "Laos",
        "currency_name": "Lao Kip"
    },
    {
        "country": "Latvia",
        "currency_name": "Latvian Lats"
    },
    {
        "country": "Lebanon",
        "currency_name": "Lebanese Pound"
    },
    {
        "country": "Lesotho",
        "currency_name": "Lesotho Loti"
    },
    {
        "country": "Liberia",
        "currency_name": "Liberian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya",
        "currency_name": "Libyan Dinar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Liechtenstein",
        "currency_name": "Swiss Franc"
    },
    {
        "country": "Lithuania",
        "currency_name": "Lithuanian Litas"
    },
    {
        "country": "Luxembourg",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Macau",
        "currency_name": "Macanese Pataca"
    },
    {
        "country": "North Macedonia",
        "currency_name": "Denar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Madagascar",
        "currency_name": "Malagasy Franc"
    },
    {
        "country": "Malawi",
        "currency_name": "Malawi Kwacha"
    },
    {
        "country": "Malaysia",
        "currency_name": "Malaysian Ringgit"
    },
    {
        "country": "Maldives",
        "currency_name": "Maldive Rufiyaa"
    },
    {
        "country": "Mali",
        "currency_name": "CFA Franc BCEAO"
    },
    {
        "country": "Malta",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Marshall Islands",
        "currency_name": "US Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Martinique",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Mauritania",
        "currency_name": "Mauritanian Ouguiya"
    },
    {
        "country": "Mauritius",
        "currency_name": "Mauritius Rupee"
    },
    {
        "country": "Mayotte",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Mexico",
        "currency_name": "Mexican Nuevo Peso"
    },
    {
        "country": "Micronesia, Federated States of",
        "currency_name": "US Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Moldova",
        "currency_name": "Moldovan Leu"
    },
    {
        "country": "Monaco",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Mongolia",
        "currency_name": "Mongolian Tugrik"
    },
    {
        "country": "Montserrat",
        "currency_name": "East Caribbean Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Morocco",
        "currency_name": "Moroccan Dirham"
    },
    {
        "country": "Mozambique",
        "currency_name": "Mozambique Metical"
    },
    {
        "country": "Myanmar",
        "currency_name": "Myanmar Kyat"
    },
    {
        "country": "Namibia",
        "currency_name": "Namibian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Nauru",
        "currency_name": "Australian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Nepal",
        "currency_name": "Nepalese Rupee"
    },
    {
        "country": "Netherlands",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Netherlands Antilles",
        "currency_name": "Netherlands Antillean Guilder"
    },
    {
        "country": "New Caledonia",
        "currency_name": "CFP Franc"
    },
    {
        "country": "New Zealand",
        "currency_name": "New Zealand Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Nicaragua",
        "currency_name": "Nicaraguan Cordoba Oro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Niger",
        "currency_name": "CFA Franc BCEAO"
    },
    {
        "country": "Nigeria",
        "currency_name": "Nigerian Naira"
    },
    {
        "country": "Niue",
        "currency_name": "New Zealand Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Norfolk Island",
        "currency_name": "Australian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "North Korea",
        "currency_name": "North Korean Won"
    },
    {
        "country": "Northern Ireland",
        "currency_name": "Pound Sterling"
    },
    {
        "country": "Northern Mariana Islands",
        "currency_name": "US Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Norway",
        "currency_name": "Norwegian Krone"
    },
    {
        "country": "Oman",
        "currency_name": "Omani Rial"
    },
    {
        "country": "Pakistan",
        "currency_name": "Pakistan Rupee"
    },
    {
        "country": "Palau",
        "currency_name": "US Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Palestine",
        "currency_name": null
    },
    {
        "country": "Panama",
        "currency_name": "Panamanian Balboa"
    },
    {
        "country": "Papua New Guinea",
        "currency_name": "Papua New Guinea Kina"
    },
    {
        "country": "Paraguay",
        "currency_name": "Paraguay Guarani"
    },
    {
        "country": "Peru",
        "currency_name": "Peruvian Nuevo Sol"
    },
    {
        "country": "Philippines",
        "currency_name": "Philippine Peso"
    },
    {
        "country": "Pitcairn Islands",
        "currency_name": "New Zealand Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Poland",
        "currency_name": "Polish Zloty"
    },
    {
        "country": "Portugal",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Puerto Rico",
        "currency_name": "US Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Qatar",
        "currency_name": "Qatari Rial"
    },
    {
        "country": "Reunion",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Romania",
        "currency_name": "Romanian New Leu"
    },
    {
        "country": "Russian Federation",
        "currency_name": "Russian Ruble"
    },
    {
        "country": "Rwanda",
        "currency_name": "Rwanda Franc"
    },
    {
        "country": "Saint Helena",
        "currency_name": "St. Helena Pound"
    },
    {
        "country": "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
        "currency_name": "East Caribbean Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Saint Lucia",
        "currency_name": "East Caribbean Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
        "currency_name": " Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
        "currency_name": "East Caribbean Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Samoa",
        "currency_name": "Samoan Tala"
    },
    {
        "country": "San Marino",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Sao Tome and Principe",
        "currency_name": " Dobra"
    },
    {
        "country": "Saudi Arabia",
        "currency_name": "Saudi Riyal"
    },
    {
        "country": "Scotland",
        "currency_name": "Pound Sterling"
    },
    {
        "country": "Senegal",
        "currency_name": "CFA Franc BCEAO"
    },
    {
        "country": "Serbia",
        "currency_name": "Serbian dinar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Seychelles",
        "currency_name": "Seychelles Rupee"
    },
    {
        "country": "Sierra Leone",
        "currency_name": "Sierra Leone Leone"
    },
    {
        "country": "Singapore",
        "currency_name": "Singapore Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Slovakia",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Slovenia",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Solomon Islands",
        "currency_name": "Solomon Islands Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Somalia",
        "currency_name": "Somali Shilling"
    },
    {
        "country": "South Africa",
        "currency_name": "South African Rand"
    },
    {
        "country": "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",
        "currency_name": "Pound Sterling"
    },
    {
        "country": "South Korea",
        "currency_name": "Korean Won"
    },
    {
        "country": "South Sudan",
        "currency_name": "South Sudan Pound"
    },
    {
        "country": "Spain",
        "currency_name": "Euro"
    },
    {
        "country": "Sri Lanka",
        "currency_name": "Sri Lankan Rupee"
    },
    {
        "country": "Sudan",
        "currency_name": "Sudanese Pound"
    },
    {
        "country": "Suriname",
        "currency_name": "Surinam Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Svalbard and Jan Mayen",
        "currency_name": "Norwegian Krone"
    },
    {
        "country": "Swaziland",
        "currency_name": "Swaziland Lilangeni"
    },
    {
        "country": "Sweden",
        "currency_name": "Swedish Krona"
    },
    {
        "country": "Switzerland",
        "currency_name": "Swiss Franc"
    },
    {
        "country": "Syria",
        "currency_name": "Syrian Pound"
    },
    {
        "country": "Tajikistan",
        "currency_name": "Tajik Somoni"
    },
    {
        "country": "Tanzania",
        "currency_name": "Tanzanian Shilling"
    },
    {
        "country": "Thailand",
        "currency_name": "Thai Baht"
    },
    {
        "country": "The Democratic Republic of Congo",
        "currency_name": "Franc Congolais"
    },
    {
        "country": "Togo",
        "currency_name": "CFA Franc BCEAO"
    },
    {
        "country": "Tokelau",
        "currency_name": "New Zealand Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Tonga",
        "currency_name": "Tongan Pa'anga"
    },
    {
        "country": "Trinidad and Tobago",
        "currency_name": "Trinidad and Tobago Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Tunisia",
        "currency_name": "Tunisian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Turkey",
        "currency_name": "Turkish Lira"
    },
    {
        "country": "Turkmenistan",
        "currency_name": "Manat"
    },
    {
        "country": "Turks and Caicos Islands",
        "currency_name": "US Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Tuvalu",
        "currency_name": "Australian Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Uganda",
        "currency_name": "Uganda Shilling"
    },
    {
        "country": "Ukraine",
        "currency_name": "Ukraine Hryvnia"
    },
    {
        "country": "United Arab Emirates",
        "currency_name": "Arab Emirates Dirham"
    },
    {
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "currency_name": "Pound Sterling"
    },
    {
        "country": "United States",
        "currency_name": "US Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "United States Minor Outlying Islands",
        "currency_name": "US Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Uruguay",
        "currency_name": "Uruguayan Peso"
    },
    {
        "country": "Uzbekistan",
        "currency_name": "Uzbekistan Sum"
    },
    {
        "country": "Vanuatu",
        "currency_name": "Vanuatu Vatu"
    },
    {
        "country": "Venezuela",
        "currency_name": "Venezuelan Bolivar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Vietnam",
        "currency_name": "Vietnamese Dong"
    },
    {
        "country": "Virgin Islands, British",
        "currency_name": "Pound Sterling"
    },
    {
        "country": "Virgin Islands, U.S.",
        "currency_name": "US Dollar"
    },
    {
        "country": "Wales",
        "currency_name": "Pound Sterlin"
    },
    {
        "country": "Wallis and Futuna",
        "currency_name": "CFP Franc"
    },
    {
        "country": "Western Sahara",
        "currency_name": "Moroccan Dirham"
    },
    {
        "country": "Yemen",
        "currency_name": "Yemeni Rial"
    },
    {
        "country": "Zambia",
        "currency_name": "Zambian Kwacha"
    },
    {
        "country": "Zimbabwe",
        "currency_name": "Zimbabwe Dollar"
    }
]
```

I am expecting to get the currency name of the country that user selects.

I get the error to say that result is an empty string.

Comment: Please post the complete error message. What if `$country != $_REQUEST['country']`?

Comment: `let countryN = $('#selCountry').text(); // when i console.log(countryN), I get the country names in the console.` - country _names_, plural? And that did not make you stop and think, something must be wrong here - since you wanted to select and send _one_ country name only, right? This should be `$('#selCountry').val()`

Comment: $('#selCountry').val() gives me a country code, and I am after country name.  I want server to be able to have access to all countries because user has a dropdown menu and depending on which country he or she selects, s/he should get relevant currency name.

Comment: @brombeer Hi, Thank you for your message. The error message says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')" and points to  $('#currency').html(result2['0']['currency_name']); Even if I remove 0 , I still get an error null, undefined. Sometimes, I do not get neither result nor error message.  I think the issue is with this or with my PHP file.

Comment: if i pass $('#currency').html(result2); in success function, i do not get any error in console or on my local server.

Answer (score 1):

your server page literally just print the currency name (you make an useless json_encode of string).
First of all check if $output is not null and so just do this:

```
$('#currency').html(result2);
```

p.s.: if you made json_encode server side, you have to do JSON.parse(result) client side, to access to the data